# ListView Item position switching and disturbs when scrolled

Tags: android, listview, scroll, chat, baseadapter

I am using ListView and BaseAdapter for filling list items inside. I am just making a simple chat application own message shows on right side and friends message shows on left side.

The problem is when i scrolls the list to view upside items the rest get disturbs like somewhere own msg is in right side and some where it is on left side.

Before Scroll

```
   Friend
           Me
   Friend
           Me
   Friend
           Me
```

After Scroll

```
   Friend
   Me
           Friend
           Me
   Friend
   Me
           Friend
   Me
```

Here is my BaseAdapter Code

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        if (names.get(position).equals(own)){
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_chat_message_own,
                    null);}
        else{
            rowView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item_chat_message_contact, null);

        }
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.message=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    String name = names.get(position);
    String message = messages.get(position);
    //Log.e("name", own+"-"+name);
    //Log.e("message", message);
    holder.message.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(this.getTextColorID()));

    if(name.equals(own))
        holder.name.setText("Me");
    else
        holder.name.setText(name);
    holder.message.setText(message);

    return rowView;
}

    @Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return names.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: You used convertView approach but you dont set in the adapter that there will be more then one row layout, Am I right?

Comment: Yes i've used convertView Approach. It shows perfect when someone send msg because at that time the adapter resets on its actual position.

Comment: Yes, I didn't point out to the adapter that there is 2 layout's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to implement `getItemViewType(position)` and `getViewTypeCount` methods in your adapter.

First of them tolds the adapter which type of row needs to be used at given position and the second one tolds the adapter how many row types it need to use

**UPDATE:**

It would be something like that:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // you have two different row types
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // You need to tell to adapter which row is needed at given position
    return names.get(position).equals(own) ? 0 : 1;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        if (getItemViewType(position) == 0){
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_chat_message_own,
                null);}
        else{
            rowView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.list_item_chat_message_contact, null);

        }
        // rest of your code
     }
     //rest of your code
 }
```

Comment: I will udpate my answer